# Enable CAN drivers in Mendel Linux

Tags: driver, can-bus, google-coral

We need to use `CAN` devices with a Coral Dev Board.  We have found that the Mendel image available for download does not have the drivers enabled.

We followed the instructions to download the kernel source files here:  https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md

We found that the `CAN` driver source files, `Makefiles`, and `Kconfig` files are present in the kernel source, for example source files:

```
linux-imx/drivers/net/can/usb/gs_usb.c
linux-imx/drivers/net/can/spi/mcp251x.c
linux-imx/include/linux/can/platform/mcp251x.h
```

And the `Makefile` for `gs_usb.c`:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
#
#  Makefile for the Linux Controller Area Network USB drivers.
#

obj-$(CONFIG_CAN_EMS_USB) += ems_usb.o
obj-$(CONFIG_CAN_ESD_USB2) += esd_usb2.o
obj-$(CONFIG_CAN_GS_USB) += gs_usb.o
obj-$(CONFIG_CAN_KVASER_USB) += kvaser_usb.o
obj-$(CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_USB) += peak_usb/
obj-$(CONFIG_CAN_8DEV_USB) += usb_8dev.o
obj-$(CONFIG_CAN_MCBA_USB) += mcba_usb.o
```

Looking through the `Makefiles` and `Kconfig` files, everything seemed to be in order with a possible exception of one line in the file:

```
linux-imx/drivers/net/Kconfig
```

We added:

```
source "drivers/net/can/Kconfig"
```

We have also tried adding the following enable flags to the `defconfig` files:

```
CONFIG_CAN=y
CONFIG_CAN_RAW=y
CONFIG_CAN_BCM=y
CONFIG_CAN_DEV=y
CONFIG_CAN_AT91=m
CONFIG_CAN_RCAR=m
CONFIG_CAN_XILINXCAN=y
CONFIG_CAN_MCP251X=y
CONFIG_CAN_GS_USB=y
```

So far without success, the `CAN` drivers are not being compiled and installed in the image, and are not on the board after we flash it.  If anyone has any suggestions, we are all ears.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I solved it as follows:

1. enable can in packages/linux-imx/debian/defconfig

   CONFIG_CAN=m
   CONFIG_CAN_RAW=m
   CONFIG_CAN_DEV=m
   CONFIG_CAN_BCM=m
   CONFIG_CAN_GW=m
   CONFIG_PROC_FS=m
2. enable usb and spi can in linux-imx/arch/arm64/configs/defconfig

   CONFIG_CAN_GS_USB=m
   CONFIG_CAN_MCP251X=m
3. add the following line to linux-imx/drivers/net/Kconfig

   source "drivers/net/can/Kconfig"
4. follow instructions to set up the repo and prepare to check out the repository:
   https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md
5. create a working directory to hold the source code.
6. cd into working directory
7. pull the repo and make changes to the files listed in 1, 2, and 3.

   repo init -u https://coral.googlesource.com/manifest
   repo sync -j$(nproc)
8. source the build files

   source build/setup.sh
9. compile the code

   m
10. connect the board
11. change to the output directory

    j product
12. update the kernel

    mdt install linux-image-4.14.98-imx_12–4_arm64.deb
13. reboot the board

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing the answer. Did you have to do any device tree modifications/overlay or changes to the platform definition? Are you using socketCAN? I followed your guide but could not see any output from the MCP251x module in the dmesg.

Comment: No modifications to device tree, overlays, or platform definition, and yes, I am using socketCAN.  I am also using a USB to CAN converter, which uses a different kernel module, which might explain why you aren't seeing any logging in dmesg.  The next time I run the stack I will run a dmesg and post a comment with the results.